# RF circuit prototyping on strip boards

Tags: rf, circuit-design, stripboard

Are strip(vero) boards good enough for prototyping RF circuits ?

Frequency range is between 100 MHz to 450 MHz.

Previously I've used strip boards for frequency range of around 100 MHz to 150 MHz, they all just worked. But I had no clue if something was wrong.

Now I want to increase the frequency range to 433 MHz with SAW resonators.

I think the capacitance between two tracks is going to make it hard.

Comment: I think a **very simple** 433 MHz circuit will be possible on a strip board but not much more than that. The capacitance between tracks does not have to be a problem if the circuit needs some capacitance between tracks. But this will not be true for all connections in a circuit. So for anything even slightly more complex than a resonator and a transistor I would not use strip board. Why not use protoboard with islands instead ? Like: http://i891.photobucket.com/albums/ac119/ekevin999/PCB/PROTOTYPE%20PCB/Kit.jpg

Comment: PCBs are *super* cheap these days. I'd just design a board and order it from China. We're talking like $12 for ten copies of a design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really must use stripboard, then 450MHz is still just within the realms of a gridded ground. With a 60cm wavelength at 450MHz, connections of a few cms are still 'short'. Create a ground XY grid using every alternate strip, and short them all across on the topside by wires, at intervals of no more than every 1.5cms, preferrably less. Trim any active strips down to the exact length you need, do not leave strips excessively long. The impedance of a strip with both adjacent strips ground will be in the 100 ohms ballpark, don't expect any wonderful impedance matching to devices that expect to see 50 ohm interfaces. However at that frequency, you can get away with a lot.

You can get stripboard with a continuous ground on the other side, which is much more usable.

A common technique used in my lab for quick'n'dirty prototyping was to use a plain copper PCB as a ground plane, and glue little islands of PCB to them, each holding an IC, or a transmission line, with components strung between them or reaching down to ground. Works tolerably to a GHz or two, with care.

Ideally you'll get a PCB fabricated.

Comment: Thanks ! It's helpful. +1 for the special type of strip board with ground plane on other side.

Comment: The vacuum wavelength of 450 MHz is 66 cm, but the wavelength on a cable or board is only about 44 cm. A quarter wavelength is 11 cm. Connections of up to 2 or 3 cm are really 'short'.